# KeyError: 'predictions' when using predict method from Tensorflow DNNClassifier.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the google machine learning crash course and am getting used to tensorflow currently, I am trying to follow along with one of the tutorials with a different dataset to learn but I am getting an error.
The dataset is from UC Irvine Repository. link:  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/balance-scale/balance-scale.data

```
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
"""Trains a neural network model.

Args:
  features: pandas DataFrame of features
  targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
  batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
  shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
  num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
Returns:
  Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
"""

# Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
features = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in dict(features).items()}

# Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, targets))  # warning: 2GB limit
ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

# Shuffle the data, if specified.
if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(50)

# Return the next batch of data.
features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
return features, labels

##############################################################
def train_model(learning_rate, steps, batch_size, hidden_units, training_examples,
            training_targets, validation_examples, validation_targets):

periods = 3
steps_per_period = steps / periods

my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

dnn_classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(),
    hidden_units=hidden_units,
    optimizer=my_optimizer,
    config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1)
)

# Create input functions.
training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_examples,
                                        training_targets,
                                        batch_size=batch_size)

predict_training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_examples,
                                                training_targets,
                                                num_epochs=1,
                                                shuffle=False)

predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(validation_examples,
                                                  validation_targets,
                                                  num_epochs=1,
                                                  shuffle=False)

print("Training model...")
print("RMSE (on training data):")

training_rmse = []
validation_rmse = []
for period in range(0, periods):
    # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
    dnn_classifier.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn,
        steps=steps_per_period
    )

    # Take a break and compute predictions.
    training_predictions = dnn_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
    training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])

    validation_predictions = dnn_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
    validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])

    # Compute training and validation loss.
    training_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(
        metrics.mean_squared_error(training_predictions, training_targets))
    validation_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(
        metrics.mean_squared_error(validation_predictions, validation_targets))

    # Occasionally print the current loss.
    print("  period %02d : %0.2f" % (period, training_root_mean_squared_error))
    # Add the loss metrics from this period to our list.
    training_rmse.append(training_root_mean_squared_error)
    validation_rmse.append(validation_root_mean_squared_error)
print("Model training finished.")

# Output a graph of loss metrics over periods.
plt.ylabel("RMSE")
plt.xlabel("Periods")
plt.title("Root Mean Squared Error vs. Periods")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(training_rmse, label="training")
plt.plot(validation_rmse, label="validation")
plt.legend()

print("Final RMSE (on training data):   %0.2f" % training_rmse)
print("Final RMSE (on validation data): %0.2f" % validation_rmse)

return dnn_classifier, training_rmse, validation_rmse
```

However i keep getting the error
line 118, in 
    training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])
KeyError: 'predictions'
I'm not really sure why the predictions are not being stored.

```
 balance_dataframe = pd.read_csv("balance.csv", sep=",")
balance_dataframe =   balance_dataframe.reindex(np.random.permutation(balance_dataframe.index))

balance_dataframe = balance_dataframe[balance_dataframe["Class"] != "B"]

data = preprocessFeatures(balance_dataframe)
target = preprocessClasses(balance_dataframe)

train_features = data.head(500)
train_classes = target.head(500)

test_features = data.tail(200)
test_classes = target.tail(200)

_ = train_model(
learning_rate=0.0001,
steps=100,
batch_size=70,
hidden_units=[10, 10],
training_examples=train_features,
training_targets=train_classes,
validation_examples=test_features,
validation_targets=test_classes)
```

Comment: What is the expected output of `dnn_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)`? You can print it out and check the data format. From the official document, I see the output should be `Evaluated values of predictions tensors.`